# Communication between WinForms apps in a large project

Tags: c#, winforms, file, inter-process-communicat

I'm working on a large project (teams are working separately) and now that most of the apps are finished, we need to integrate everything together. A lot of apps/forms need to communicate information to other apps/forms or solicit information from others; I wonder if there are standard ways of doing this. The way we are planning to do that is through the use of shared files (e.g. one app writes info to a file and the other reads it). Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends very much on what you want to share, and when.  Could you add some context? Roughly describing the workflow that your various apps participate in would help - as well as whether these apps are co-resident on the same box, constitute part of a distributed application, etc.

Comment: I would use a central database to communicate.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi It's a language learning app (client-server). Here is a quick scenario: teacher logs in (account mgmt app) -> teacher create/edits/... quizes or tests, grades finished exos and so on (test createion app). The latter app needs the teacher's credentials to work.

Comment: @UweKeim Thanks, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @Uwe Keim said in a comment, you should definitely use a database for everything. A SO answer is not the place to start teaching you about relational databases and how to use them properly from C# applications, though. You should tell the person managing the teams that's the way to go, and have them figure out who to hire to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As regards your question, I think that there is an obvious drawback in using the file-shared solution, which is the delay in your operation because of IO operations.

Moreover, there are other options, please see below:

To fully implement your requirements, you should separate the communication between applications and the communication among forms inside a application.

To implement communication between applications, I would suggest that you use the subscriber/publisher pattern using WCF. The implementation is quite easy. You can google it. One example is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22796/WCF-Implementation-of-the-Publisher-Subscriber-Mod). By doing that, you could control exactly when something happens and the other application should re-acts as you expects.

To implement communication amongst forms in an application, it'd better to create an event aggregator using the Pub/Sub pattern, and then inject it into your application. You can have a look at how it implemented in [SCSF](http://smartclient.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to implement a message protocol to make the apps communicate each other.
To avoid bottlenecks, a `message queue` service can manage the messages exchange.

References:

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing)
- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)